# How to count database occurrence when grouped by a field

Tags: php, sql, group-by, count

I have a table with 2 rows lets say, 'user' and 'action'. it lays out as such -

```
user    |    action

bob          page view
mike         detail view
bob          page view
mike         page view
bob          detail view
```

I would like to group the query by user and count each action occurrence for said user like so -

```
bob = (2) page views (1) detail view
mike = (1) page view (2) detail views
```

I have tried group by but it limits each query to 1 since its being grouped like so -

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY user";
```

and then using if statements -

```
if($action == 'page view'){
    $pv++;
}
```

I know there is a correct way to do this in the statement without using if statements but not sure how.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it in SQL directly:

```
SELECT user, action, count(*) as total
FROM table 
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

Comment: Thanks! could you explain how this works a little, what does 1 and 2 represent in the grouping?

Comment: GROUP BY 1, 2 is equivalent to GROUP BY user, action.

Comment: So using this method, where do i get the different grouped actions for each user? Do I use something like $user = $row['user'] and $action = $row['total']?

Comment: The above query will first group by user, then by action (page view, detail view) and output for each the number of occurrences. Bob will have 2 rows: (1) bob - page view - 2 and (2) bob - detail view - 1

Comment: is it a MySql syntax?

Comment: @YuriyTsarkov it's generic SQL syntax, should work for everything.

Comment: Yes I get that output thank you, my trouble is putting it inline in a table or something like - user | page view | detail view and then bob | (1) | (2)

Comment: Run the above SQL and it's going to do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the database engine to return the total page / detail view for each user all in one row you will have to use a conditional branch statement. The following query will return all your users along with their page views and detail views:

```
SELECT user,
SUM(CASE WHEN action = 'page view' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS page_view,
SUM(CASE WHEN action = 'detail view' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS detail_view
FROM table
GROUP BY user;
```

Comment: This is very clever Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes perhaps sql can directly do this 
`Select user,count(*),(distinct action) from table group by user`